# [Gazebo 9] Could not find parameter robot_description on parameter server

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-melodic, gazebo-ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I know this question is asked a couple of times before, but I just couldn't find the right answer for me.
So I'm trying to launch my URDF model with gazebo plug in and use ros_control package to control the movement. But as soon as rover_control.launch run, the error (Could not find parameter robot_description on parameter server) appears.
Now, I think this happens because I messed up something in my launch file, my yaml and my urdf. So I will quote three of them here. Thank you for your patient, this is my first week of learning ros.

Control launch file:

```
<launch>

  <!-- Load joint controller configurations from YAML file to parameter server -->
  <rosparam file="$(find rover_project)/rover_description/config/rover_control.yaml" command="load"/>

  <!-- load the controllers -->
  <node name="controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false"
    output="screen" ns="/rover" args="left_wheel_holder_to_left_wheel right_wheel_holder_to_left_wheel joint_state_controller"/>

  <!-- convert joint states to TF transforms for rviz, etc -->
  <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher"
    respawn="false" output="screen">
    <remap from="/joint_states" to="/rover/joint_states" />
  </node>

</launch>
```

YAML file:

```
rover:
  # Publish all joint states -----------------------------------
  joint_state_controller:
    type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
    publish_rate: 50  

  # Position Controllers ---------------------------------------
  left_wheel_holder_to_left_wheel:
    type: effort_controllers/JointPositionController
    joint: left_wheel_holder_to_left_wheel
    pid: {p: 100.0, i: 0.01, d: 10.0}
  right_wheel_holder_to_left_wheel:
    type: effort_controllers/JointPositionController
    joint: right_wheel_holder_to_left_wheel
    pid: {p: 100.0, i: 0.01, d: 10.0}
```

And the URDF file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<robot name="Rover Platform">

  <material name="blue">
    <color rgba="0 0 0.8 1"/>
  </material>

  <material name="grey">
    <color rgba="0.2 0.2 0 1"/>
  </material>    

  <link name="base_link">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="1.0 1.0 0.2"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="blue"/>

    </visual>

    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <box size="1.0 1.0 0.2"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>

    <inertial>
      <mass value="5"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.83333" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.433333" iyz="0.0" izz="0.433333"/>
    </inertial>
  
  </link>

  <link name="right_wheel_holder_link">

    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.3 0.2 0.2"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="blue"/>
    </visual>

    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.3 0.2 0.2"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>

    <inertial>
      <mass value="1"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.011" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.0067" iyz="0.0" izz="0.011"/>
    </inertial>

  </link>

  <link name="left_wheel_holder_link">

    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.3 0.2 0.2"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="blue"/>
    </visual>

    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.3 0.2 0.2"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>

    <inertial>
      <mass value="1"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.011" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.0067" iyz="0.0" izz="0.011"/>
    </inertial>

  </link>

  <link name="right_wheel_link">

    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.25"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="grey"/>
    </visual>

    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.25"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>

    <inertial>
      <mass value="1"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.00021" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.0" iyz="0.0" izz="0.00021"/>
    </inertial>

  </link>

  <link name="left_wheel_link">

    <visual>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.25"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="grey"/>
    </visual>

    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.25"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>

    <inertial>
      <mass value="1"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.00021" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.0" iyz="0.0" izz="0.00021"/>
    </inertial>

  </link>

  <joint name="base_to_right_wheel_holder" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="right_wheel_holder_link"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.4 0.2 -0.2"/>
  </joint>

  <joint name="base_to_left_wheel_holder" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="left_wheel_holder_link"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.4 0.2 -0.2"/>
  </joint>

  <joint name="left_wheel_holder_to_left_wheel" type="continuous">
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <parent link="left_wheel_holder_link"/>
    <child link="left_wheel_link"/>
    <origin rpy="0 -1.57075 0" xyz="-0.15 0 0"/>
  </joint>

  <joint name="right_wheel_holder_to_right_wheel" type="continuous">
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <parent link="right_wheel_holder_link"/>
    <child link="right_wheel_link"/>
    <origin rpy="0 1.57075 0" xyz="0.15 0 0"/>
  </joint>

  <transmission name="tran1">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="left_wheel_holder_to_left_wheel">
      <hardwareInterface>EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="motor_left">
      <hardwareInterface>EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>

  <transmission name="tran2">
    
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="right_wheel_holder_to_left_wheel">
      <hardwareInterface>EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="motor_right">
      <hardwareInterface>EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>

  </transmission>

  <gazebo>
    <plugin name="gazebo_ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
      <robotNamespace>/rover</robotNamespace>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>

</robot>
```

Just in case something is also wrong with my gazebo launch file:

```
<launch>
  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch"> 
  </include>

  <node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" ns="/rover" args="-file $(find rover_project)/rover_description/urdf/rover.urdf -urdf -z 1 -model diff_rover" />
</launch>
```

Thank you so much for your patient!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/336906/%5Bgazebo-9%5D-could-not-find-parameter-robot_description-on-parameter-server/) by [vitsensei](https://answers.ros.org/users/48858/vitsensei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2019-11-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey people from the future, I figured it out.
What I did to fix this is to add the following to rover_control.launch:

```
<param name="robot_description" command="cat $(find rover_project)/rover_description/urdf/rover.urdf"/>
```

So for some reason, the launch file cannot find the URDF model, I guess. So we have to show ros the way.

---

Originally posted by [vitsensei](https://answers.ros.org/users/48858/vitsensei/) with karma: 96 on 2019-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2